# Ported MVC3 VS2010 app to MVC4 VS 2012 - Membership fails

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am piecing together a new MVC4, VS 2012 app from MVC3 2010.

I run the app, log in (do NOT remember login credentials) run the app making various calls to the Membership classes to get User details. All works well, I close the app and re-run, again logging in without remembering credentials, all still runs fine.

My problem is when I select remember me option. after logging in all works well. When I close the app and restart, I get an 'unable to find SQL Server' error whenever my code requests `Membership.GetUSer()`. I'm confused, can anyone help?

PS Meant to say, My Web.config points to SQL Server 2008 R2. I created the membership tables by initially creating a User.